# How do I delete multiple files in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I wanted to delete multiple files from Artifactory using their CLI, but it's not letting me.

./jfrog rt del "barbarian/CSS/2.12.8-1+gccb456e/PR-495/0/package/";"barbarian/BS/2.12.8-1+gccb456e/PR-495/0/package/" --quiet

I am getting no such file or directory

If I do these individually, it works so the path is correct.  It is just not allowing me to delete them simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use 1 of 2 options:

Set wildcards in your Delete path, and if needed in your `--exclude-patterns` to get to your desired list of artifacts you'd like to delete

or

Use a file spec (`--spec`) with your delete command, and specify the list of patterns you'd like to delete, for example, something like:

```
{
"files": [
 {
    "pattern": "barbarian/CSS/2.12.8-1+gccb456e/PR-495/0/package/"
 },
 {
    "pattern": "barbarian/BS/2.12.8-1+gccb456e/PR-495/0/package/"
 }
]}
```

you can find more regarding the different options in the CLI's delete command [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFiles)